# Read ASCII-File with missing data fields with numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, genfromtxt

My data file is like this:

```
abb
sdsdfmn
sfdf sdf

2011-12-05 11:00                                         1.0        9.0        
2011-12-05 12:00                                        44.9        2.0        
2011-12-05 13:00                                        66.8        4.2       
2011-12-05 14:00       22.8        1.0       26.2       45.2        2.3      
2011-12-05 15:00       45.7        2.0       45.0       45.6        1.4      
2011-12-05 16:00       23.2        3.0      456.2       11.7        1.5      
2011-12-05 17:00       67.4        4.0      999.1       45.8        0.9  
2011-12-05 18:00                                        34.4        1.2
2011-12-05 19:00       12.4        4.2      345.1       11.1        7.6
```

I used numpy genfromtxt:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', usecols=(0,1,3), skip_header=4, dtype=[('date','S10'),('hour','S5'),('myfloat','f8')])
```

The Problem is column 3 has some empty values in there (at the beginning and later on). So it read a wrong column.

I tried the delimiter-parameter, because all float columns has fixed width (delimiter=[10,5,5]), but it also fails.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: `genfrontxt` isn't as good as `pandas` when handling this sort of missing data. Or you could write your own reader from basic python. That shouldn't be hard,  What's the failure with the fixed column definition.?

Comment: When using the fixed width, it refers only to the column where values in it. It doesn't find the gaps. There are basically only spaces between.

Comment: It reads and splits a line one at a time.  The layout of line 4 does  not affect how it handles line 1.

Comment: Let's say we have line 1 : I think it selects "2011-12-05", "11:00" and "9.0". What i need is : "2011-12-05", "11:00" and "  ". In line 4 : "2011-12-05", "14:00" and "26.2". That's correct.

Comment: I know what you want.  But `genfromtxt` has no way of knowing that the big block of spaces in the middle of line 1 are 'supposed' to contain 3 columns.  With the default `whitespace` delimiter, that's just one delimiter, not 3.  With the fixed width delimiter, you need to account for all columns, not justed the 'used' ones.

Comment: OK! I found this workaround: Creat a pandas dataframe: df = pandas.read_fwf('data.txt', colspecs='infer', skiprows=4). Work's fine!